# Full System Backup and Restore

Tags: backup, system

I've been tinkering with Ubuntu and found that it's pretty easy to brick my system. My only solution so far would be to format my disk and reinstall everything from scratch, but this is obviously very repetitive and time consuming work.

The simplest way I can think of to backup would be to copy my install, byte for byte with `dd` and make a .img file. However, reading around it seems to only work if the target disk is the same size as the original disk. I can understand it won't physically fit if it were smaller, but why not larger? My current install is on a 16GB flash disk, and I'd like to at least be able to restore directly back to this disk instead of having to wipe the disk and reinstall and customize back to my liking (apps, extensions, tweaks, browser settings, etc). Disk is a single partition with an ext4 file system. Bootloader is also installed to the same disk (install ubuntu at /dev/sdc1 and bootloader at /dev/sdc1). As a bonus, I'd like to also be able to move my install to a larger "proper" disk if I can.

Summary: can I use `dd` to backup my Ubuntu install byte for byte and restore it later to the same disk, and is there a better way to do a full system backup

Thank you for your time.

Comment: When you `dd` why not of= to a file instead of drive/device, or to a partition (thus only part of a device)?  if=input.file (devices are files in \*nix, but you can use *real* files too, ditto of=).   A better way is use specific; and I rarely format before install (you can install without format; where it'll re-add back your additional added software, not touch user data too).  If you're bricking your system, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @guiverc I can mount a hard disk where Windows is installed. Suppose my install is on /dev/sdc1 and Windows is on /dev/sda4 and mounted on /mnt/windows, would I do: `dd if=/dev/sdc1 of=/mnt/windows/system.img` and restore with `dd if=/mnt/windows/system.img of=/dev/sdc1` from a live disk?

Comment: @404NameNotFound: TIP: you don't have to play around with `dd`, you can simply do `cp /dev/sdc1 /mnt/windows/` or even `cat /dev/sdc1 > /mnt/windows/system.img`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Thanks! Are there any advantages / disadvantages over using one method over the other?

Comment: It's easier to use than dd and it can be even faster in some cases https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/dd-vs-cat-is-dd-still-relevant-these-days. `dd` is good for binary editing, for example for replacing n-th byte in a file.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Ah I see. And to restore I would copy this file I generated back to the disk, not needing any reformatting, correct? Suppose my disk was full when it broke, and when I restore it would just take up whatever space Ubuntu needs and blank out the rest, exactly how the system was when I took the backup?